# Unable to removedata from modal on close.Showing same content everytime

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Unable to removedata from modal on close.Showing same content everytime

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

This function is also not working.

Comment: Is there any method for clearing cache of modal everytime it is relaunched.

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Had a same problem, when i am passing data to same modal, and remove content. The best solution, and only got is to use bootBox

http://bootboxjs.com/

```
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "I am a custom dialog",
  title: "Custom title",
  buttons: {
    success: {
      label: "Success!",
      className: "btn-success",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("great success");
      }
    },
    danger: {
      label: "Danger!",
      className: "btn-danger",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("uh oh, look out!");
      }
    },
    main: {
      label: "Click ME!",
      className: "btn-primary",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("Primary button");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I cannot use bootbox here.several dropdown and input types are there.

Answer (score 0):

try in this way for Bootstrap v3.2.0

```
$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $(e.target).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").empty();
});
```

example of generic modal

```
<div class="modal hide" id="">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>

    </div>    

    <div class="modal-body">

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: faby check my html http://jsfiddle.net/ovtj3jxu/

I m totally confused about div Ids in above script.

Comment: @shakun your code is completely unreachable. please put just relevant code and load external libraries

Comment: any example you can give where above script is used.

The main <div> id  <div class="md-modal md-effect-12 md-show" id="modal-12">
                <div class="md-content modal-content">

Comment: not working.now i m using this $('.md-close').click(function() {
           window.location.reload()
        });

Answer (score 0):

men i can finally made ir works

shoud be.

```
        $('body').on('hide.bs.modal', '.modal', function (e) {
        $(this).find('form').trigger("reset");
    });
```

in this post [I cant clear form data from bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986951/i-cant-clear-form-data-from-bootstrap-modal/28986975?noredirect=1#comment46222692_28986975)  Sadikhasan user nailed it, you need to clear form data but $(this) is the modal div, so you need to find the form inside the modal and reset it.