# I can't clear form data from bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a little problem when im trying to clear bootstrap modal data..
there is my modal.

```
    <div id="modal-creacion-alias" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <form id="form-alias-dominio" method="POST" class="form">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                            <h2 class="modal-title">Alias de dominios</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nombre del Alias<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div class="input-icon right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle tooltips" data-original-title="Contraseña" data-container="body"></i>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre-alias-dominio" id="nombre-alias-dominio">
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer ">
                            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">Cancelar <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></button>
                            <button type="submit" id="crear-alias-domino" class="btn gtd-blue-hard crear-alias-domino">Crear <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the js function:

```
  $('body').on('hide.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        &(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
```

but when i close and re open modal the data still there.
how can i solve it?

thanks.

Comment: `&(this)` is `$(this)` in production, right?

Comment: sorry its a question mistake lol really im using $ insteas & (wronk key)

Comment: Trust me it is next to impossible. i asked same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224696/unable-to-removedata-from-modal-on-close-showing-same-content-everytime. but nothing works.i end up with the solution of refreshing page everytime to clear data.

Comment: `.on('hide.bs.modal', '#modal-creacion-alias', function () {`

Comment: What is `this` in this callback? will it log anything if you add `console.log($(this).data('bs.modal'))` to this callback

Comment: Also - have you tried using the `hidden.bs.modal` event? Maybe bootstrap doesn't let you delete anything while the `hide` event is in progress?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset all input data by using `$(form).trigger('reset')`

```
$('body').on('hide.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
       $('#form-alias-dominio').trigger("reset");  //here your form_id
});
```

Comment: i tried             
        $(this).trigger("reset");
and this
      $('#form-alias-dominio').trigger("reset");
and none of both works

Comment: You need to do `$("#form_id").trigger("reset");` I implemented in my code and working fine. Downvoter please comment for `downvote ?????`

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but (like in the previous thread) can explain to you that there is a difference between `resetting the form` and `clearing the data` that is stored in the `.data()`

Comment: @skip405 I dont know difference but this code implemented in my project and it works fine that's why I suggested If not useful then I will delete it.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to clear data doing this

```
   $('body').on('hide.bs.modal', '.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('form').trigger("reset");
});
```

thanks @Sadikhasan