# How clear bootstrap modal on hide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How to can you clear the bootstrap modal on dismiss/hide/close?

I have the following Modal definition:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   Add New Comment
</button>
```

**Partial view which contains Modal**

```
@Html.Partial("_CreateComment", Model)


 // Partial view which contains modal

 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddComment", "Blog", new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "comments",
                OnSuccess = "$('#myModal').modal('hide');"

            }))
      {
        <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Comment</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Blog.BlogID)

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BlogComment.Comment)
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.BlogComment.Comment, 4, 104, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BlogComment.Comment)
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      }
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is the javascript I am using to to clear the content:

```
$(function () {
    //clear modal cache, so that new content can be loaded
    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');

    });
});
```

If I dismiss the modal after having entered some content or upon submission the content in the form doesn't clear?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

this is the easiest fix:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find("input,textarea,select").val('').end();

});
```

Comment: Solved it for me. Thanks

Comment: I recommend using `.val([])` if you wish to clear `select` also. Also, `.end()` is not needed in this case, it is especially useful to reset the state when chaining.

Comment: how to clear input type="checkbox"? I've try by putting `input type="checkbox"` & `input#id` but this doesn't work.

Comment: This solution was removing the value of my submit button on my modal. I used the solution of @GuruprasadRao.

Comment: @RaphaelMonteiro You can filter... $(this).find('input:not([type=submit]), textarea, select').val([]);

Comment: @WafieAli This code works too for checkbox $(this).find('input, textarea, select').val([]);

Answer (score 9):

Use `val('')` based on input types present and use `#myModal` instead of `body`

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.modal-body').find('textarea,input').val('');
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/o4wvdkLe/1/)**

Comment: It doesn't work? I add content to the text field and click close then reopen the modal and content in the text field is still there?

Comment: That removes entire body including the input fields? I need the input fields still there, just the content inside the input fields to be cleared.

Comment: @ozzii- i asked same question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224696/unable-to-removedata-from-modal-on-close-showing-same-content-everytime).but i never got the answer so i used location.reload to clear my modal every time.

Comment: easiest is to do ` $(this).find("input,textarea,select").val('').end();` which fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $(".modal-content").empty();
      });
```